# Using Flutter's CustomPaint, is it possible to draw a transparent path with solid color edge?

Tags: flutter, path, draw, paint, transparent

I'm working on a drawing app using Flutter. How can I draw a path with transparent color and a solid color edge surround the path?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different blend modes but couldn't achieve what I want so I implemented in following way. It's an expensive operation but it works as expected.

double iw=20;
double ow=25;

```
Path mPath1=Path;
Path mPath2=Path;

Color color_alpha=Color.fromARGB(10,255,255,255);

for(int i=0; i< points.length; i++)
{
    mPath1.addOval(Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(pt.dx, pt.dy), width: iw, height: iw));
    mPath2.addOval(Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset(pt.dx, pt.dy), width: ow, height: ow));
}

canvas.drawPath(Path.combine(PathOperation.difference, mPath2, mPath1), Paint());
canvas.drawPath(mPath1, Paint..color=color_alpha);
```

Here is the result.

[image]